# Unit Tests fail to load when solution is on a network share (LAN)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

i'm using **Visual Studio 2012** and cannot see any Unit Tests when i go to the **TestExplorer**.

The solution is is a **network share**.

I already tried adding `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>` to various **.config** files, and even making the network share **"Fully Trusted"** using **caspol.exe**.

My network share is mounted as unit **X:**, so the command looks like this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -machine -addgroup All_Code -url X:\* FullTrust
```

I also tried adding `<legacyCasPolicy enabled="true" />` to the config without luck.

**If I try to Debug the Test directly using Resharper plugin, the error I get is:**

> Unable to get type
>   ProductDataModules.DataModel.Tests.TSD_InformationModule.
>   Error: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///X:\Source\ProductDataModulesTests\bin\Debug\ProductDataModulesTests.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131515) File name:
>   'file:///X:\Source\ProductDataModulesTests\bin\Debug\ProductDataModulesTests.dll'
>   ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly
>   to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This
>   release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default,
>   so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox
>   the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
>   AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestFramework.TypeCache.LoadType(String
>   typeName, String assemblyName)

Did anybody have this issue? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 refused to trust my **network share**.

However I found a workaround to foolish it (make it assume my environment is on a local drive):

First of all, I had to map the network unit **permanently**, it asked for the user and password to authenticate. I chose to remember credentials, so that the trust relationship loads automatically even after a restart or shutdown.

Then I had to make a **symbolic link** from cmd.exe, using the following command:

```
mklink /D c:\symLink \\192.168.0.206\<share name>
```

Now I had to browse to the new path, and open the .SLN file.

I could even make a shortcut to my Desktop.
The link now points to **c:\symLink...\solution.sln**

I never had a permission bug again. Hope it helps.